# Grep multiple files with multiple unique words

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to extract lines from ~1200 files. What I have at the minute is a text file with the following format:

```
"1" "keyword1" "filename1"
"2" "keyword2" "filename2"
"3" "keyword3" "filename3"
"4" "keyword4" "filename4"
and so on.
```

What I want to do is check filename"n" for the line containing keyword "n". I'm guessing this can be done using some sort of loop in a bash script like as follows

```
for (i in 1:n){ 
grep "dataframe[i, 2]" dataframe[i,3]}
```

but I'm really struggling to get my head how to actually program that in a BASH script as I'm used to using R.

Comment: Something like this maybe? `while read -r id keyword file; do grep $keyword $file; done < inputFile`

Comment: No. A shell (e.g. bash) is an environment from which to call tools with a language to sequence those calls. Any time you find yourself writing a shell loop just to manipulate text files you have the wrong approach. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219 for some of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Iterate over the file, reading one line at a time
#For each line read 3 columns
while read -r col1 col2 col3; do
  #remove leading and trailing quotes (") with sed
  pattern=`sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' <<<"$col2"`;
  file=`sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' <<<"$col3"`;
  echo "Matches in $file:"
  #find matches with grep
  grep "$pattern" "$file";
  echo ""
done < list.txt
```

Add whatever arguments you want to grep, like `-n` for line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
awk -F'"' 'NR==FNR{ARGV[ARGC++]=$6; word[$6]=$4; next} $0 ~ word[FILENAME]' file
```

It can easily be made more robust and/or more efficient depending on your unspoken needs (e.g. what output you want, whether or not the same file can appear multiple times with different words, whether the comparison should be regexp or string, partial or full, etc).